# Showing multiple messages in one toast in React

Tags: reactjs, react-toastify

I want to show 3 messages in One single toast. Once the toast is launched , in the same toast show next set of messages. Infact i want to do concatenation of messages. How do i do this in React

Comment: Please share your code @nanda

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by appending jsx in your **`react-toastify`** this way: Check this [**Link**](https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify/issues/201#issuecomment-402646895) for more info:

**Example Code:**

```
toast.error(<div>{this.trans.invalid}<br /> sorry</div>, { position: toast.POSITION.UPPER_RIGHT });
```

This way, you can append messages as well as customize it according to your requirements.

Let me know, If you have any other questions.